# Like Button Icon Change svg

Tags: php, html, svg, icons

I have a Like Button with an ICON. Can someone guide me how to change the icon of the text ? I tried with `<img src=>` . But it doesn't change, I don't know what I need to change for changing the text icon.
Here is the code :

```
    <?php if ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'reaction') { ?>
        <!-- reaction -->
        <?php if ( isset($wo['story']['viewmode']) && $wo['story']['viewmode'] == 'lightbox') { ?>
        <div class="wo-reaction wo-reaction-lightbox stat-item unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>">
            <span class="like-btn like-btn-lightbox unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" >
                <?php
                    if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']) === true) {    
                        echo Wo_GetReactedTextIcon($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']);
                    } else {   
                        echo '<span class="status-reaction-'.$wo['story']['id'].' unselectable"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> <span class="t_likes'.$wo['story']['id'].'"></span> ' . $wo['lang']['like'] . '</span>';   
                    }    
                ?>
            </span>
            <ul class="reactions-box reactions-lightbox-container-<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?> unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" style="<?php if ($wo['language_type'] == 'rtl') {?> left: auto; <?php }else{ ?> right: auto; <?php }?>">

                <?php if (!empty($wo['reactions_types'])) {
                    foreach ($wo['reactions_types'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['status'] == 1) {

                     ?>
                    <li class="reaction reaction-<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-reaction-id="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this,'<?php echo($value['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($value['is_html']) ?>);">
                        <?php if (preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$value['wowonder_icon'],$m)) {
                                echo($value['wowonder_icon']);
                             }
                             else{ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo($value['wowonder_icon']) ?>">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php } } } ?>



                <!-- <li class="reaction reaction-like" data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--like">
                        <div class="emoji__hand"><div class="emoji__thumb"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-love" data-reaction="Love" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['love'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--love">
                        <div class="emoji__heart"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-haha" data-reaction="HaHa" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['haha'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--haha">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth">
                                <div class="emoji__tongue"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-wow" data-reaction="Wow" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['wow'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--wow">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-sad" data-reaction="Sad" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['sad'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--sad">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-angry" data-reaction="Angry" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['angry'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--angry">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>

        <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="wo-reaction wo-reaction-post stat-item unselectable" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>">
            <span class="like-btn like-btn-post unselectable"  data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" id="react_<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" <?php if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id'])) { ?> data_react="1" <?php }else{ ?> data_react="0"<?php } ?> data-reaction-id="<?php echo $wo['reactions_types'][1]['id'];?>"  data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReactionLike(this,'<?php echo($wo['reactions_types'][1]['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($wo['reactions_types'][1]['is_html']) ?>);">
                <?php
                    if ($wo['loggedin'] && Wo_IsReacted($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']) === true) {    
                        echo Wo_GetReactedTextIcon($wo['story']['id'], $wo['user']['user_id']);
                    } else {   
                        echo '<span class="status-reaction-'.$wo['story']['id'].' unselectable"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> <span class="t_likes'.$wo['story']['id'].'"></span> ' . $wo['lang']['like'] . '</span>';   
                    }    
                ?>
            </span>
            <ul class="reactions-box reactions-box-container-<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" style="<?php if ($wo['language_type'] == 'rtl') {?> left: auto; <?php }else{ ?> right: auto; <?php }?>">
                <?php if (!empty($wo['reactions_types'])) {
                    foreach ($wo['reactions_types'] as $key => $value) {
                        if ($value['status'] == 1) {

                     ?>
                    <li class="reaction reaction-<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-reaction-id="<?php echo $value['id'];?>" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $value['name'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this,'<?php echo($value['wowonder_small_icon']) ?>',<?php echo($value['is_html']) ?>);">
                        <?php if (preg_match("/<[^<]+>/",$value['wowonder_icon'],$m)) {
                                echo($value['wowonder_icon']);
                             }
                             else{ ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo($value['wowonder_icon']) ?>">
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php } } } ?>



                <!-- <li class="reaction reaction-like animated_2" data-reaction="Like" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--like">
                        <div class="emoji__hand"><div class="emoji__thumb"></div></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-love animated_4" data-reaction="Love" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['love'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--love">
                        <div class="emoji__heart"></div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-haha animated_6" data-reaction="HaHa" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['haha'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--haha">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth">
                                <div class="emoji__tongue"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-wow animated_8" data-reaction="Wow" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['wow'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--wow">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-sad animated_10" data-reaction="Sad" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['sad'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--sad">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="reaction reaction-angry animated_12" data-reaction="Angry" data-reaction-lang="<?php echo $wo['lang']['angry'];?>" data-post-id="<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>" onclick="Wo_RegisterReaction(this);">
                    <div class="emoji emoji--angry">
                        <div class="emoji__face">
                            <div class="emoji__eyebrows"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__eyes"></div>
                            <div class="emoji__mouth"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li> -->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>

    <?php }else{ ?>

      <!-- Normal Like -->
      <span onclick="Wo_RegisterLike(<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>);" id="like-button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" title="<?php echo $wo['lang']['like'];?>">
      <?php
      $second_btn_wonder = ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'dislike') ? $wo['lang']['dislike'] : $wo['lang']['wonder'];
      $second_btn_wondered = ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] == 'dislike') ? $wo['lang']['disliked'] : $wo['lang']['wondered'];
      if ($wo['story']['is_liked'] === true) {    
        echo '<span class="active-like"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> ' . $wo['lang']['liked'] . '</span>';   
      } else {   
        echo '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-thumbs-up"><path d="M14 9V5a3 3 0 0 0-3-3l-4 9v11h11.28a2 2 0 0 0 2-1.7l1.38-9a2 2 0 0 0-2-2.3zM7 22H4a2 2 0 0 1-2-2v-7a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h3"></path></svg> ' . $wo['lang']['like'];   
      }    
      ?>
      </span>
      <?php if ($wo['config']['second_post_button'] != 'disabled') { ?>
      <span onclick="Wo_RegisterWonder(<?php echo $wo['story']['id']; ?>);" id="wonder-button" class="btn btn-default stat-item" title="<?php echo $wo['second_post_button_text'];?>">
      <?php 
      if ($wo['story']['is_wondered'] === true) {  
        echo '<span class="active-wonder">' . $wo['second_post_button_icon'] . '<span class="like-btn-mobile">' . $second_btn_wondered . '</span></span>'; 
      } else {    
        echo '' . $wo['second_post_button_icon'] . ' <span class="like-btn-mobile">' . $second_btn_wonder . '</span>';
      }
      ?>          
      </span>
      <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>
```

Near the text I have an icon...I want to change that icon with an other image..I don't have a folder with all svg images..I think its a link.

Comment: That's a lot of code. Which icon/text are we talking about? Can you reduce this to the essentials?

Comment: This is the Button code..This is all script for that button.. Like-Button.php